# How do I create uint8_t with byte data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledata, uint8t

I am trying to create uint8_t data with 2 bytes, and when I log the information after I have created it the saved information is incorrect(Or I am misunderstanding the LLDB logs).

```
uint8_t terminatingMessage[2];
terminatingMessage[0]=0x9E;
terminatingMessage[1]=0xEB;
NSMutableData *terminatorData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:(const void *)prepareMessage length:2];
```

When I break and log my "terminatorData" the value I get is `B0F0`. What I want and expect is to see `9EEB`... What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating `terminatorData` from `prepareMessage`, but it looks like you meant to have `terminatingMessage`.

Comment: Thank you - It's been a long week